# Simple JSON parsing not working in POST to Spring API

Tags: java, rest, spring-rest

I've defined a simple API with a JSON object called Foo in the request body:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/foo", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Foo> foo(@RequestBody Foo request) {
    log.info("request:{}", request);
    log.info("request.id:{}", request.getId());
    return new ResponseEntity<Foo>(request, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is the `Foo` class definition:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
    String id;
}
```

Here is the curl script:

```
curl --location 'localhost:8080/notification-api/foo' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"id":"a string"}'
```

But the `requst.id` value is always null from within the `foo()` method when the curl script is called.

Comment: That code works fine for me. I believe that the most common errors might be the use of an incorrect `RequestBody` import or a failure in your lombok integration. Check both.
Also, I assume you don't have another method to handle GET requests...

Comment: @KyreX: Yep, swagger snuck in:

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @KyreX ... if you post an answer I'll accept it.

The problem was that the RequestBody came from the wrong import:

```
*import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;*
```

rather than:

```
*import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;*
```